# request "Unauthorized" when using Cognito User Pool Authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Similar questions have been asked here and other places, but I'm stuck...

I have a user pool set up as the authorizer for my REST API and the method, which point to a Lambda function (proxy integration). I can go through the sign-in process but I get 401 Unauthorized -- **without it hitting the Lambda at all** (no logs appear for the lambda function, and the API Gateway logs just show that it was an unauthorized request). I see the id_token in the URL -- but it's not sent as the Authorization header. If I take that id_token and use Postman to run the request with that in the Authorization header, it works.

I'm sure I'm missing some kind of configuration that would send those parameters in headers instead of in the URL, but I can't find it.

fwiw, I'm just serving up static HTML pages from the endpoint in question...
I've set the app client to accept either Google or the Cognito User Pool user auth. Same results.

Comment: I'm not clear about the issue. What you mean " I see the id_token in the URL -- but it's not sent as the Authorization header". Are you the one build and call API? I'm using the same model and it is working fine for me. Please clarify more.

Comment: Yes, I built the API. I'm getting the id_token as a URL parameter on my redirect URL at the end of this process. BUT, API Gateway stops the request before it gets to Lambda, so I never even see that request (with the URL param) come through...

Comment: You can call me via Hangouts at bigzidane@gmail.com to share screen for me.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Nghia. I haven’t tested this out, but I think I know the problem... my redirect_uri is the *authenticated* page... I think I need to change that to an open page and redirect with the provided id_token.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what the issue was? I'm having the same issue. Where the Cognito Hosted UI login page has the callback URL but doesn't include the token in the header for that request.